# why does the loop Printing till 11 instead of 10?

Tags: c++, loops

i have this simple program in C++ to see usage of continue statement. i am running loop from 1 to 10 skipping 5, but this print until 11 which i guess is false condition. where am i getting wrong?i want to print 1 to 10 skipping 5.

```
\\
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i=1;

while(i<=10)
{
    i++;
    if(i==5)
    {
        continue;
    }
    cout<<i<<endl;
\\


}
}
```

Comment: you increment the number at the start of the loop, im guessing you get 2 -> 11 instead of 1 -> 10

Comment: Try to simulate the loop in a thought experiment. What happens on the last iteration? When `i = 10`?

Comment: Isn't this a nice sample to learn how to use the debugger to understand the behavior of the written code?

Comment: This seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: when i put the counter outside the braces of IF statement it only print 2 to 5. And if i put the i++ before or after the continue statement it print infinite loop of 1.

Comment: Maybe the compiler likes [Spinal Tap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOO5S4vxi0o) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

what you are doing here is incrementing variable "i" before printing it. Correct code should look something like

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i=1;
    while(i<=10){
        if(i==5){
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        cout<<i<<endl;
        //incrementing variable after printing
        i++;
    }
}
//output
//1234678910
```

your code must be giving output as below 
23467891011

Comment: it seems either my compiler is stupid. i just copied your code. pasted in Code::Block still the output is 1234

Comment: With all due respect your code is wrong because when it reaches value 5 the continue block runs which not only exits the if loop but also exits the while loop so values only print till 4

Comment: @TalhaIsrar it doesnt exit the while loop

Comment: Oh it looks like you edited the code. Sorry didnt take that in notice

Comment: so did i, and it doesnt exit the while, although there is a better way of writing the code

Comment: @dvijparekh your updated code works perfect,thanks. and Talha i really wanted to carry this with the use of continue statement but i don't know why the **continue** statement in above program behaves as **break** statement.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you have placed the increment operator

```
 i++;
```

after  you have entered the loop iteration.

So when loop starts with i=10 it comes on i++ first and the prints i

Use this code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int i=1;

while(i<=10)
{
    if(i!=5)
    {
    cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    i++;

}
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `after you have initialized the value` should be `after you have entered the loop iteration`

Comment: thanks for help but i don't understand where to put the increment operator as placing it after the if condition or continue statement create infinite loop. the program run correct only when i initialized to 0. i<10 and then it works fine placing loop write after while statement.

Comment: @imrankay place it just before the end of the `while` loop

Comment: instead of if(i==5)  place if(i !=5) and place the cout statement inside the loop and place the increment statement outside the loop and after the loop

Comment: @mast3rd3mon placing it before the end of loop , i.e after cout statement only prints till 1 until 4.

Comment: Use if loop not a while loop

Comment: The OP wants a continue statement.

Comment: oh ok. But someone has answered the question so i thought no need to change this code :)